# How to insert data to table on spring boot application start?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

How can I insert data to a table on `Spring Boot` application start? My application is generated by `JHipster`. What I need to check is that if that particular data already exist in that table or not. If it doesn't I should add it.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already? Any articles on the topic you've read? Do you have a specific error  you're getting?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement an [`ApplicationRunner`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html) and use a repository to do whatever you need to do.

If the `ApplicationRunner` is a spring bean it is run on application startup.

For more sophisticated requirements I would try to rely on a tool like [flyway that has good integration with spring boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup)

Comment: thanks. I have created a bean. Kept a method with `@PostConstruct` annotation. Called services from the method. Working fine.

Answer (score 2):

If your application was generated by JHipster, then it should already include and be properly configured for Liquibase.

You have a few options:

- You can use Liquibase's [insert](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/insert.html) change to insert data.
- You can put your data in a CSV file and use the [loadData](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html) change to load it. Look for the `loadData` tag in `00000000000000_initial_schema.xml` for examples.
- You can use the [sql](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) change to run native SQL directly.

All three options can be combined with [preconditions](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) to make sure the data doesn't exist before trying to insert it. If you need the changeset to run every time you boot your application, you can use the `runAlways="true"` attribute (docs for that are on [this](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html) page).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in your **service class** which checks if the data already exists or not and if not then save that data.