# Jhipster : How to populate DB with Liquibase at start

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster, I have created a monolithic application and I would like to know how could I automatically create entity in my H2 database when my application start in dev ?

I've seen some csv file in /resources/config/liquibase that seems to create the users and the authorities but I don't know how to create other entities with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert data to table on spring boot application start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253508/how-to-insert-data-to-table-on-spring-boot-application-start)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new Liquibase ChangeSet that uses the ext:LoadData element.  Within this element you need to specify each column you want to populate.

```
<changeSet author="Joe Bloggs" id="42">
  <ext:loadData identityInsertEnabled="true" commentLineStartsWith="#"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            file="config/liquibase/changelog/data/foo.csv"
            quotchar="&#34;"
            separator=","
            tableName="FOO">
     <column name="bar" type="STRING"/>
     <column name="baz" type="STRING"/>
  </ext:loadData>
</changeSet>
```

Then in your foo.csv file you can add your values (the first row is headers, subsequent rows are the data):

```
"bar","baz"
"bar1","baz1"
"bar2","baz2"
"bar3","baz3"
```

Comment: To answer fully to the question which was to load it only for h2 in dev, you could add a condition on `dbms="h2"` or on `context="dev"`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

Edit the "added_entity" xml in  your config/liquidbase/changelog (example:20180606131920_added_entity_Product.xml) and add after the createTable tag:

```
        <loadData encoding="UTF-8"
              file="config/liquibase/product.csv"
              separator=";"
              tableName="product">
    </loadData>
```

and of cource create a product.csv at the specified location